# Vue Run-time MultiSelect Component creation with CreateApp - Failing to Bind Model Value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

I am trying to create a multiselect component at run-time (not at design time). Following is the sample code I am trying.

My multiselect options:

```
const regions = ref([
   { label: 'Queensland', value: 'QLD' },
   { label: 'New South Wales', value: 'NSW' },
   { label: 'Victoria', value: 'VIC' },
   { label: 'Tasmania', value: 'TAS' },
   { label: 'South Australia', value: 'SA' }]);
```

My dynamic component is created as below:

```
const generateMultiSelectDynamically = (field: string) => {
   var el = document.createElement("div"); //create container for the app
   el.style.display = "inline"

   let selectedRegions = ref();
   var componentApp = createApp(
    MultiSelect, {
    maxSelectedLabels:1,
    options: regions.value,
    optionLabel:(v: any) => `${v.label}`,               
    placeholder: `region`,
    name: `region`,
    multiple:true,
    filter:true,
    // modelValue: selectedRegions
   });

   componentApp.use(PrimeVue);  // Using PrimeVue
   componentApp.mount(el); //mount to DOM
   document.getElementById(field)!.appendChild(el);
   document.getElementById(field)!.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '))
}
```

To see if the options are showing up properly, I have temporarily commented out *modelValue*. This is displaying the options correctly as below.

[image: Multiple region options display]

But if I bind it (uncomment the binding code), and then click on the multiselect, I am receiving the following error.

> TypeError: this.modelValue.some is not a function

[image: Error msg]

So, somehow the binding is not correct. What am I doing wrong?

Tried ref(), ref([]) as *selectedRegions*, didn't work.

Comment: Maybe you need to append `el` to the DOM before you mount the vue app on the element? Have you tried that?

Comment: Also, you may need to call `this.modelValue.value.some()` instead of `this.modelValue.some()`. `ref()` produces reactive objects and requires that you access the wrapped value through the `.value` property.

Comment: @cSharp, thanks for the suggestion. However, the appending of el to DOM is probably not the issue as we have similar other dynamic components (e.g. drop-down and calendar components) which load alright and follow this similar flow. Something to do with modelValue which I am having difficulty with.


@IVOGELOV, thanks for the suggestion. I tried like the following.
`
modelValue: selectedRegions.value
`

Now the error is gone, but items cannot be selected. And chrome debugger console also not showing any error.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked. The two-way data-binding actually didn't take place when we create the control dynamically (even though that works alright at design-time).

***selectedRegions*** needs to be a ref of array

```
ref([])
```

***modelValue*** needs to be the value of the ref variable (as is the rule for ref variable).

```
modelValue: selectedRegions?.value
```

And the selection needed to be set in the ***onChange*** event.

```
onChange: (event: any) => {
  selectedValues.value?.splice(0, selectedValues.value.length);
  event.value.forEach((element: any) => {
      selectedValues?.value?.push(element);
  });
```

***splice*** is used to clear out the model as each click event comes with only the selected items. After clearing, we push the value to the model.

So the overall code looks like below.

```
var componentApp = createApp(MultiSelect, {
  maxSelectedLabels: 3,
  options: regions,
  optionLabel: (v: any) => `${v.selectionLabel}`,
  placeholder: selectionName.toLowerCase(),
  name: selectionName,
  multiple: true,
  filter: true,
  modelValue: selectedValues?.value,
  onChange: (event: any) => {
    selectedValues.value?.splice(0, selectedValues.value.length);
    event.value.forEach((element: any) => {
        selectedValues?.value?.push(element);
    });
  },
});
```

[image]